# Firefox shortcut not working

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Ubuntu (14.04) I  find that the Firefox shortcut for downloads `Ctrl+J` doesn't work.

Pressing `Ctrl+J` always takes me to the Firefox default home page (the one with the big Firefox logo in the middle and the search box underneath).

Other shortcuts such as `Ctrl+Shft+A` or `Ctrl+H`, `Ctrl+B`, etc. work just fine. I find this very odd. It's been the case since the clean install, i.e. it can't be due to another application.

Why could this be happening? How can I resolve this, without getting a external plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, that your Firefox uses another shortcut. You should see the correct shortcut in the menu bar (for example in my browser "Tools" -> "Downloads Ctrl-Shift-Y").

There are cases when Ctrl-J is assigned another function, e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546380

Comment: Thank you, `Ctrl Shft Y` did the trick. I had tried `Ctrl Y` previously but to no avail. But this is a rather annoying bug I must say, makes individual Firefox installations non-standard at random..